# Geodesic curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Clairaut’s theorem. How to prove that geodesic curvature parallel Radius of the surface of revolution (i. e the value inversed to geodesic curvature) is equal to tangential line segment and meridian closed between the point of tangency and surface axis.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5F0u.jpg)

I know that I should use the Clairaut's theorem.But I have no idea how to prove it. Can you help me to prove this?